# React: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations.ts

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access an asset to use in a css declaration...

```
import FooterBackgroundDesktop from "../../assets/register-bg.png";

"background-image": `url(${FooterBackgroundDesktop})`
```

However, although the path to assets and the filename is correct, I get the following error:

**Cannot find module '../../assets/register-bg.png' or its corresponding type
declarations.ts(2307)**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
"background-image": url("../../assets/register-bg.png")
```

or you can do this

```
let FooterBackgroundDesktop = "../../assets/register-bg.png";

"background-image": url(FooterBackgroundDesktop)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This only part fixes the issue.. My next issue is that only SVG are displayed ... see here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75258347/react-why-are-only-svg-files-displaying-for-background-image-css-in-a-styled-co